# How can I work on files on my server and keep them in sync?

Tags: linux, debian, vmware, web-deployment

I have set up a development web server using VMWare and Debian. It's all set up fine, but I have an problem.

I need to be able to work with the files on the server, or a copy of them. But, it's important that both sets of files are in sync. For example, in my text editor if I'm working on `index.php` I don't want to have to upload with FTP each time, and I don't want to manually keep track of what files I've edited etc.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: This sounds like job for version control software (like [git](http://git-scm.org/), for example).

Comment: But wouldn't that mean I have to commit and push everytime I make a save?

Comment: yes, but that's a feature. imagine you are in the middle of implementing a new feature, and the casual **save** will sync the server with only half-ready (and thus broken) content. having to `git push` make the step of deployment explicit, and thus more robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides version controlling you can achieve it with sshfs. It is basically like mounting a remote directory in your local system.

More info:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh

Answer (score 0):

After much searching I felt the best solution for my case is to use `lsyncd` to upload files to the development server anytime a change is made.

Although I use `git` I felt setting up a Git server and having to `commit` and `push` every time I make a change isn't what I want to be doing. Using `lsyncd` I'm able to use `git` on my local machine to keep track of the project.

Comment: you don't need a *git server*. having `git` and `ssh` installed on the target server should be enough.